# Where can I download ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Might sound like a stupid question I guess but rubyonrails.org is just an advert right now, which isn't a good sign.

Comment: Wow.  Someone forgot to renew the domain.  It expired yesterday.

Comment: @zombat.  Second year in a row... DHH drives a Lamborghini.  You think he could afford a 10 year renewal.

Comment: Help me!! Waht is 2+2?? 4, I said. NEGATIVE VOTE, "i knew that, it happens that my calculator is broken" you say

Comment: @Daniel Dolz while you might think my attitude is 'bad' from your comment left down below, I'm a beginner to Ruby and I just happened to try to download it while their site was down. Pointing me to the site while it's just an advert wasn't in any way helpful, but thank you for your input.

Comment: When i posted, the site was working ok. I do not deserve a negative vote. It is working ok now

Comment: I'll up vote your question to make up for Daniel's inability to read.  rubyonrails.org is definitely down today ( http://twitter.com/dhh/status/12525309898 ). Maybe Daniel's browser cache is working just fine.

Comment: Daniel.  Maybe you are going to the .com, and not the .org.  .com is up today (when it normally isn't)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://rubyonrails.org

Except that they are having some domain registration problems today.  It should be back up within 24 hours.

Until that is back up, it looks like http://rubyonrails.com will work for you.

See http://twitter.com/dhh

Comment: Thank you, should probably have checked the .com myself!

Comment: The .com is not usually up.  It usually redirects to the .org.  But as a short term fix, they set the name servers to the .org's server ips.

Answer (score 4):

http://rubyonrails.com

David Heinemeier Hansson tweets:

http://twitter.com/dhh/status/12537282169

http://twitter.com/dhh/status/12533585916

http://twitter.com/dhh/status/12525309898

Answer (score 3):

install rubygems, they type "gem install rails" from the commandline. There were some domain name issues with the hosting provider today, should be cleared up in the next few hours.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, they are down (today?).

- GitHub ( http://github.com/rails/rails )
- Or a RubyForum well written guide, working links ( http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=34 )

Answer (score 1):

Or if you have Rubygems installed:

`gem install rails`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the site is currently having problems with its domain registrar, see [here](http://www.railsinside.com/news/427-gorgeous-blonde-whos-not-dhh-takes-over-official-ruby-on-rails-site.html). Hopefully they should be resolved before too long and these links should work.

Comment: At the time of posting, there were already a good 3 or 4 links to the Ruby website. I didn't feel like my answer needed to contribute to this redundancy, but I did want to let the OP know that the site was down (which, at the time of posting, no one else had mentioned yet).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download Ruby www.ruby-lang.org
Rails is a Ruby gem, so after installing Ruby, in a console you would enter 
gem install rails

Check out http://guides.rails.info/3_0_release_notes.html#orm-abstraction-and-action-pack-interface to get started with the latest beta release of Rails 3

Or http://www.railstutorial.org/book#sec:up_and_running or similar for basics on Rails 2.X

Answer (score 0):

You can find the rails gems and download here: http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=307